# Import data into R with an unknown number of columns?

Tags: r, import

I'm trying to read a text file with different row lengths:

```
1
1   2
1   2   3
1   2   3   4
1   2   3   4   5
1   2   3   4   5   6
1   2   3   4   5   6   7
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
```

To overcome this problem, I'm using the argument fill=TRUE in read.table, so:

```
data<-read.table("test",sep="\t",fill=TRUE)
```

Unfortunately, to assess the maximum row length, read.table reads only the first 5 lines of the file, and generates an object looking like this:

```
data
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1   1 NA NA NA NA
2   1  2 NA NA NA
3   1  2  3 NA NA
4   1  2  3  4 NA
5   1  2  3  4  5
6   1  2  3  4  5
7   6 NA NA NA NA
8   1  2  3  4  5
9   6  7 NA NA NA
10  1  2  3  4  5
11  6  7  8 NA NA
```

Is there a way to force read.table to scroll over the whole file to assess the maximum row length?
I know a possible solution would be to provide the column number, like:

```
data<-read.table("test",sep="\t",fill=TRUE,col.names=c(1:8))
```

But since I have a lot of files, I wanted to assess this automatically within R. Any suggestion? :-)

---

EDIT: the original file doesn't contain progressive numbers, so this is not a solution:

```
data1<-read.table("test",sep="\t",fill=TRUE)
data2<-read.table("test",sep="\t",fill=TRUE,col.names=c(1:max(data1))
```

Comment: Can you put a header in the file (i.e. do the files have a consistent format)?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the files are generated externally and every row can have a random number of entries.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

There is nice function `count.fields` (see help) which counts number of column per row:

```
count.fields("test", sep = "\t")
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

So, using your second solution:

```
no_col <- max(count.fields("test", sep = "\t"))
data <- read.table("test",sep="\t",fill=TRUE,col.names=1:no_col)
data
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8
# 1  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
# 2  1  2 NA NA NA NA NA NA
# 3  1  2  3 NA NA NA NA NA
# 4  1  2  3  4 NA NA NA NA
# 5  1  2  3  4  5 NA NA NA
# 6  1  2  3  4  5  6 NA NA
# 7  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 NA
# 8  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
```

Answer (score 6):

Using `count.fields` is definitely the right approach for this, but just for completeness:

Another option is to bring in all the raw text and parse it within R:

```
x <- readLines(textConnection(
"1\t
1\t2
1\t2\t3
1\t2\t3\t4
1\t2\t3\t4\t5
1\t2\t3\t4\t5\t6"))
x <- strsplit(x,"\t")
```

To combine a list of unequal length vectors, the easiest approach is to use the `rbind.fill` function from `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)
# requires data.frames with column names
x <- lapply(x,function(x) {x <- as.data.frame(t(x)); colnames(x)=1:length(x); return(x)})
do.call(rbind.fill,x)
1    2    3    4    5    6
1 1 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
2 1    2 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
3 1    2    3 <NA> <NA> <NA>
4 1    2    3    4 <NA> <NA>
5 1    2    3    4    5 <NA>
6 1    2    3    4    5    6
```