# how to read the data contain different columns in R?

Tags: r

```
data='
编号,性别,序号,民族,籍贯,系部
1,男,20130990,壮族,广西省,旅游系
24,男,20130520,汉族,广东省,经管系
25,男,20130521,汉族,海南省,经管系
26,男,20130522,汉族,海南省,经管系
27,男,20130523,汉族,海南省,经管系
28,男,20130524,汉族,浙江,经管系
29,男,20130525,汉族,浙江,经管系
30,女,20130526,汉族,海南,经管系
31,女,20130527,汉族,江西省,经管系
32,男,20130528,汉族,浙江,经管系
33,男,20130529,汉族,海南省,经管系
34,男,20130530,黎族,海南省,经管系
48,女,20131065,汉族,河北省,艺术系,,
49,女,20131066,汉族,湖南省,艺术系,,
50,女,20131067,汉族,广东省,艺术系,,
51,男,20131068,汉族,海南省,艺术系,,
52,男,20131069,汉族,海南省,艺术系,,
53,男,20131070,汉族,重庆市,艺术系,,
127,男,20130338,汉族,江西省,经管系
128,男,20130339,汉族,海南省,经管系
129,男,20130340,汉族,海南省,经管系
130,男,20130341,汉族,四川省,经管系
131,男,20130342,汉族,四川省,经管系'
```

how to read the data with read.table  in R ?
There are 6 columns in some lines ；7 columns in some lines(6 colunmes +1 blank column),these lines end with two commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have asian fonts installed hence using the below sample text:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f
x,2,3,4,5,6
y,6,5,4,3,2,1
```

Here the columns are unequal with 6,6, and 7 in rows 1,2,3 including the header.

From this ([Import data into R with an unknown number of columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874443/import-data-into-r-with-an-unknown-number-of-columns))

saving the contents to `somefile.csv`

```
no_col <- max(count.fields("somefile.csv", sep = ","))
data <- read.csv('somefile.csv',fill=TRUE,col.names=1:no_col)
>data
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7
1  x  2  3  4  5  6 NA
2  y  6  5  4  3  2  1
```

Here `count.fields` counts the number of columns and the `col.names` are generated based on number of columns

You could change the column header using,

```
colnames(data)<- namevector
```

where namevector is the vector containing the column names you require