# How do you import an external correlation matrix from file in R?

Tags: r, matrix, correlation, read.table, data-import

I have a 6x6 correlation matrix that I want to import:

```
 1.0000
 0.6008   1.0000
 0.4984   0.4749   1.0000
 0.1920   0.2196   0.2079   1.0000
 0.1959   0.1912   0.2010   0.4334   1.0000
 0.3466   0.2979   0.2445   0.3197   0.4207   1.0000
```

I've tried using scan() directly, but it won't input the matrix.

`A <- matrix(scan("data.txt", n = 6*6), 6, 6, byrow = TRUE)`

This didn't work because "data length [21] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [6]".

What other methods can be used to import an external, pre-existing correlation matrix?

Comment: use `read.table()`if the data is a .txt file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import data into R with an unknown number of columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874443/import-data-into-r-with-an-unknown-number-of-columns)

Answer (score 3):

You could indeed use `count.fields` and `read.table` alone ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874443/import-data-into-r-with-an-unknown-number-of-columns)), but I think the most appropriate solution is to make a symmetric matrix with [xpnd](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/MCMCpack/docs/xpnd) from `MCMCpack` (no `NA`'s in UD).

```
max_col <- max( count.fields("data.txt", sep = " ") ) # Insert \t if tab-separated 

library(MCMCpack)
A <- read.table("text.txt", sep=" ", fill=TRUE, col.names=1:max_col)
corr <- xpnd( A[lower.tri(A, diag=T)] , max_col)
```

Giving you

```
corr
#        [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]
# [1,] 1.0000 0.6008 0.4984 0.1920 0.1959 0.3466
# [2,] 0.6008 1.0000 0.4749 0.2196 0.1912 0.2979
# [3,] 0.4984 0.4749 1.0000 0.2079 0.2010 0.2445
# [4,] 0.1920 0.2196 0.2079 1.0000 0.4334 0.3197
# [5,] 0.1959 0.1912 0.2010 0.4334 1.0000 0.4207
# [6,] 0.3466 0.2979 0.2445 0.3197 0.4207 1.0000
```