# Prevent R from splitting columns to rows during data import

Tags: r

I have a data file with 21 rows but the no. of columns in each row are different. The first column is the header and remaining columns have numbers.

[Full text file is here.](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AmwHhkcRA6qljSHzjARlqQNotiXk)

So, I import the file using: `d <- read.table("data.txt", sep = " ", fill=T)`. But when I looked at the data using `view()`, I see that one row with a lot of columns (160,000+) is split into 3 rows. [A picture showing this phenomenon is here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UK1Vc.png)

Why is R doing this? And how can I fix it so I get 21 rows? I'd appreciate any help/pointers. I am using R Studio (64 bit) on Windows 7 with 16 GB memory.

Also, I did look around before posting but did not have much luck. The 'reshape' package seemed at first to be of some help but I couldn't really use it to suit my needs. Any tip to fix the issue during import or post-import would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It would be useful if you posted `dput(d)`, so we can import your dataset, instead of making a screenshot of your data.

Comment: It's a pretty long file. Instead, I've added a link to the text file.

Comment: Seems related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874443/import-data-into-r-with-an-unknown-number-of-columns), which is about how `read.table` decided the max number of columns.  Some answers there that you can try.

Comment: You can try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626637/reading-a-text-file-in-r-line-by-line approach also and read the lines to a list and then try reshaping data according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this appears is that `read.table` only checks out the first 5 rows of `test.txt` to determine the maximum length of the rows. In your data, the ninth line exceeds that maximum and therefore shows some weird behaviour.

You can avoid this by telling `read.table` how many columns it should create by giving them names as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874443/import-data-into-r-with-an-unknown-number-of-columns). The number of elements per line in some can be found using `count.fields`:

```
# Find the number of elements per line in test.txt
perline <- count.fields("test.txt", sep = " ")
maxlength <- max(perline)

# Read in test.txt
d <- read.table("test.txt", sep = " ", 
                row.names = 1, col.names = 1:maxlength,
                fill = TRUE)
```

Comment: Nice! Telling it to use the max # of columns seemed to do exactly what wanted. Thanks Ken. Also thanks to @aosmith.